# Selenium: Unable to access chrome internal pages in headless mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser, remotewebdriver

All chrome internal pages (e.g., *chrome://downloads*) are showing blank in headless mode and working in normal mode.

### Code to reproduce (Java)

```
webdriver.get("chrome://downloads/");
System.out.println(webdriver.getPageSource());
```

### Output

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

### Output Without headless argument (and nothing else changed)

*chrome://downloads* page is successfully opening 
able to get 1533 lines as source

### Details

> **Selenium Java:** 3.141.59 
>   **ChromedriverVersion:** 83.0.4103.39 
>   Using remote web driver 
>   **OS:** MacOS 10.15.4

### Chrome Options

```
options.addArguments("headless");
options.addArguments("disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("disable-application-cache");
options.addArguments("disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process");   //for network calls of iframes
options.addArguments("no-sandbox");                                         //for running in docker without chrome user
options.addArguments("disable-dev-shm-usage");                              //write shared memory files into /tmp instead of /dev/shm
options.addArguments("user-agent="+"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36");

options.setExperimentalOption("w3c", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
```

It's important for me to open downloads page and I don't want to use file reader in downloads folder or anything.